# Index may be explicitly disabled using is_write_index=false

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Logs are not publishing and filebeat showing below warning

```
2023-08-07T12:06:32.359Z WARN [elasticsearch] elasticsearch/client.go:414 Cannot index event publisher.Event...
.
.
.
{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no write index is defined for alias [filebeat-7.17.1]. The write index may be explicitly disabled using is_write_index=false or the alias points to multiple indices without one being designated as a write index"}, dropping event!
```

What will be the solution

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you get from `GET _cat/aliases/filebeat-7.17.1?v` ?

Comment: alias           index                             filter routing.index routing.search is_write_index
filebeat-7.17.1 filebeat-7.17.1-2023.07.22-000068 -      -             -              false

Comment: @Val I found the solution and will add it as a Answer

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

When there is an abnormality in pushing to the latest index in an index pattern after some time, that indes will mask as suspended with the param **is_write_index=false**

We need to remove that lock by setting the param value as **true**

1. Login to the Kibana portal
2. Go to **Dev Tool** under **Management** section

[image]

3. Past the below code and update the index name and the alias

> ```
> POST /_aliases
> {
> "actions" : [
>     {
>         "add" : {
>              "index" : "<index_name>",
>              "alias" : "<alias_name>",
>              "is_write_index" : true
>         }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Note : alias name will start as ***filebeat-***

Official documnetation  : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/indices-aliases.html#aliases-write-index

4. As soon as you perform the above action, logs will start to push to the index